# jQuery not displaying span iteration properly

Tags: jquery, image, iterator, html

So I've created an erb block that gets the coordinates for each image tag, in which I want to display the tag for each image at said coordinates. However, only a single tag is being displayed, not every tag in the iteration. Any idea why? Does it have something to do with .each()?

```
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
<% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
<span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"> </span>  
<br>
<div class='image_panel'>
    <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class='planetmap'></div>


<% end %>
<% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span.i_connection").each(function() {
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width'); 
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    $(".tagged_box").css("display","block");
    $(".tagged").css("border","5px solid red");

    if ((xpos !== undefined) && (ypos !== undefined)) {
    console.log('X:' + xpos + 'px' + ' ' + 'Y:' + ypos +'px');         
        $('.planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
        pos_height+'px;left:'+xpos+'px;top:'+ypos+'px;" ><div class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
        pos_height+'px;display:none;" ></div>')
         }
});   //END OF SPAN.CONNECTION ITERATION
});
```

**EDIT**
So I changed the id's to classes and now the tags show up for each photo. Success! However it still shows both of them, not their respected tag. Which I believe has something to do with the .each() method.

**EDIT #2 LATEST CODE**

The block iterates through 2 images.
Now .tagged shows up on both images instead of one tag per respected image

```
<div class="container">
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>

<span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"> </span>
<br>
<div class="image_panel">
    <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
        <div class='planetmap'></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("span.i_connection").each(function() {
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    $(".tagged_box").css("display","block");
    $(".tagged").css("border","5px solid red");

    // if ((xpos !== undefined) && (ypos !== undefined)) {
    // console.log('X:' + xpos + 'px' + ' ' + 'Y:' + ypos +'px');         
        $('.planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+pos_height+'px;left:'+xpos+'px;top:'+ypos+'px;" ><div class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
            pos_height+'px;" ></div>')
         // }
});   //END OF SPAN.CONNECTION ITERATION
});
</script>   

<% end %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML from your ERB block, if the problem is with `jQuery.each()` then it will be easier for people to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow what your final generated HTML looks like from the code you provided but one error that jumps out is your `span` has a class of `"i_connection"` while your jQuery selector is looking for a span with the class of `"connection"`.  This actually should cause the `.each()` to not run at all though, so this might not be all of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems I see in your code:

1. You are setting `<span class="i_connection"` but using `$("span.connection").each(function() {` as already pointed by Jason.
2. You have multiple `divs` with same `id` i.e. `image_panel` and `planetmap`.  `id`s are supposed to be unique in one entire DOM document.

To fix the first problem you should change your `$("span.connection").each(function() {` to use the correct class i.e.

```
$("span.i_connection").each(function() {
```

I'm assuming you want the `image_panel` div to only show if the `<% if @new_manual.present? %>` evaluates to true.  That fixes the one of the duplicate `id` problem.  For the second duplicate ids on `planetmap`, I'm again assuming that you want it outside of the `<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>` based on the `JS` code I see.  Please update your erb as follows and see if this is what you want:

```
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
  <div class='image_panel'>
    <% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
      <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
      <span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"> </span>  
      <br>

      <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
    <% end %>
    <div id='planetmap'></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So I fixed 1. and 2. and updated my ERB to what you suggested, however the first image has a tag but the second doesn't. Also if I change the erb to this:
<div class="image_panel">
  <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
  <% end %>
 <div class='planetmap'></div>
 <% end %>
</div>
The second tag shows but the first doesnt

Comment: @EricFilkins, when you say `tag` are you referring to `html elements` or your classes?  Another problem I see is that you only have one closing div `</div>` for two open divs `<div>` in your javascript.Where are you adding the images, please post that code as well.  Also it would be better to post your latest code so that we get a better picture.